# What is the best way to store large no of images in Android?

Tags: android, image, storage

I have to store large no of images (around 50,000) through my application & each image has size around 400KB. I want to store all these images in SD card & I can, but I want to do it in better way.Because I will also need to encrypt/decrypt all these files & of course retrieving back.

So anyone please, Guide me how should I approach this.

Comment: So you want to store 20Gigs of images on Android? In a single app?

Comment: Ouch!! Around 50000 on an SD Card? Quick math = 19 odd GB eh?

Comment: Yes it can increase upto this much.

Comment: Are you aware that most Android devices don't even have this much storage?

Comment: I am working for an dedicated Android device.So the app won't be for any device.

Comment: Wouldn't storing them on a server and accessing them when needed do a much better job? Kinda like the Zedge app if you would.

Comment: @Siddharth Yes it will.But first I have to store all images in device.

Comment: how about integrating the app with dropbox?

Comment: Why do you **have** to store all the images on the device? Why is that a requirement?

Comment: @ppeterka basically the app will be used on rural areas, so initially I will have to store images in device itself.

Comment: First of all decide what device are you going to use for this, cause you can't expect much device support here, if it's  going to be locally distributed. I'm sure it is, cause 20GB app from the market place is just a bloody joke. Majority of Android devices are having 4-16GB of storage and that event cut down because of the OS and other apps taking space. OR implement a web service get the images on request and find WiFi one way or the other in rural areas.

Answer (score 0):

Most Android devices won't even have this much storage. If you store these images on the device then the device will have to be a higher-priced one which will put it out of the reach of most of your target users (I am assuming it is farmers etc from your comment that it is for people from rural areas).

If price is not an issue and you have to store these images on the device then these might help:

- [Efficient Way to store images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393494/efficient-way-to-store-images-in-android)
- [what is the best practice store images in android in SD card or in SQL lite DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539130/what-is-the-best-practice-store-images-in-android-in-sd-card-or-in-sql-lite-db)

Answer (score 0):

Besides considering not storing the images on the device due to huge size, you should consider putting them into single container for ease of management. If you don't plan to update the image set on device, you can use ZIP archive. If you want to update the images on the fly, some virtual storage system, such as our Solid File System (SolFS), would work. SolFS supports flexible file encryption (both whole-storage and per-file), compression and other features of advanced file systems. And you can download the complete container and update it easily after that.